# Client/Server Communication Between GWT Client and a Desktop-run Server

Tags: java, html, gwt, networking

I'm attempting to write a browser based MMO using libGDX and it's HTML5/GWT port and I have no idea how to do the client/server interactions. I have already written the application for desktop as a sort of "learning" project for myself, and have now decided to rewrite it into the browser.

I have never done browser development before, so I'm not quite sure of how to go about doing the networking portion of the project. I fear that this is because I'm not quite sure as to how GWT actually works, especially when being used for what I'm doing. I attempted to use a library called KryoNet for the networking but apparently you cannot use normal networking methods for GWT. I received this error: http://pastebin.com/DVJPA44N

In short, I need help/direction with how to do a client/server communications type deal with GWT if it's even possible. If there is an easy google answer I apologize, I'm not sure how to word what I'm looking for.

Thank you!

---

EDIT: I looked at the WebSockets API, and that's not quite what I'm looking for. I want to host a server locally off the desktop and communicate to the client hosted in the browser. I apologize if I'm just misunderstanding the whole servlet setup in GWT.

Comment: GWT -> Client Java Code compiles to javascripts and runs in a Browser. GWT -> Server Java (servlet)compiles to normal java byte code and runs in jee web container like jetty,tomcat,websphere ( run on a server )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have look at something like [PlayN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/) ( Angry Birds is top example using it with GWT for Browser port of the application )

Also you need to checkout WebSocket API ( either direct use in GWT/JSNI or via third-party gwt jar )

Comment: WebSocket API looks good. It's unfortunate that there doesn't seem to be a cross-platform easy solution for this. I'd prefer to stick with libgdx as that is what I'm familiar with and PlayN doeesn't seem to have any outstanding features that I would need to switch from using LibGDK.

Comment: Indeed HTML5 is bleeding edge. Since you are mentioning cross platform in mobile space, You might as well google on Titanium, PhoneGap, mgwt and Sencha technologies whether they have what you are looking for. Note - those are the top ones in the cross platform space when you use GWT.

Comment: I did some research and it seems that WebSockets aren't what I'm looking for, or perhaps I'm not understanding it correctly. I'm looking to host a server locally and communicate with the client embedded in a browser.

Comment: GWT -> Client Java Code compiles to javascripts and runs in a Browser. GWT -> Server Java (servlet)compiles to normal java byte code and runs in jee web container like jetty,tomcat,websphere ( run on a server )

Comment: I did not word my problem correctly because I did not know enough about the subject. Your answer is definitely correct for what I said, and I thank you!

Comment: Do publish a open source project and share if you find/write a sample websocket programming project with GWT :)